# Writing daemon in objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, daemon

I need to write a daemon, much like windows service on os x using objective c. Can anyone point to some sample? or guide me about how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to write your program in a way that lets it be run in the foreground, and then use external tools and techniques (such as OS X's [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ)) to run them detached. This makes your program easier to test and integrate.

Comment: Is it possible to run os x application written in objective c to run as deamon using launchd?

Comment: Why not follow the link I've provided to the documentation, and find out there?

Comment: so there is no class in cocoa framework which makes os x app run as a service just like in windows world?

Comment: by the way jonathan, thanks for helping out. I need to write my own sever kind of app which always runs in the background.

Comment: Nirvana, *read the docs*. See the section "Required Behaviors".

Comment: Nirvana, please remove the duplicate questions here: stackoverflow.com/questions/1841393/writing-daemon-in-objective-c