# Writing daemon in objective c

Tags: macos, daemon

I need to write a daemon, much like windows service on os x using objective c.
Can anyone point to some sample? or guide me about how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a complete technical note available on the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2005/tn2083.html).

You will find all the needed information, as well as the restrictions for creating, launching and debugging a daemon, whatever its language.

See also [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840162/writing-daemon-in-objective-c) on SO.